# Stop Facebook videos pre-loading

Tags: google-chrome, facebook

I currently have an internet access with limited quota. I recently started to notice that videos displayed in the news feed are automatically pre-loaded even without interacting with them at all which consumes much bandwidth and eats up the quota.

Is there any way to stop this behaviour?

I am using Google Chrome browser on Windows 7.

P.S: I am not sure if this is the correct community to post this question, if it's not please guide me where to ask this.

Answer (score 0):

To stop videos auto-playing on Facebook, you must go to the Facebook settings, and find 'Video Settings' on the left tab. You can change the 'Auto-Play Videos' setting to 'OFF'.

Comment: There is no "Auto-play" setting, I only have "Video Default Quality" setting.

Comment: umm, the autoplay setting should be there, after video default quality setting...

Comment: That's weird, I double checked and I don't have that option.

Comment: Alright, the option decided to show up and it's the auto-play is already "Off". However the videos are still pre-loading on the news feed. Videos does not auto-play, however, if I play them, they always have a part or all the video already buffered and loaded.